# AmXYChart - How to add padding to prevent hidden overflows

Tags: amcharts

I have create a simple XY Chart graph with percent as y axes and customers as x axes, I randomised the data between 0...100% with a set of 184 points. and have a bit of difficulty display the lower/upper region values. I have included an image for the demonstration.

[image]

Here my config file, I cant seem to find some sort of offset/padding ?

```
{
  type: 'xy',
  addClassNames: true,
  autoMargins: false,
  marginLeft: 67,
  marginBottom: 55,
  graphs: [{
    balloonFunction,
    bullet: 'round',
    xField: 'customers',
    yField: 'rate',
    bulletSize: 16,
    lineColorField: 'color',
  }],
  valueAxes: [
    {
      title,
      borderThickness: 0,
      axisThickness: 2,
      maximum: 100,
      labelFunction: (e,val) => { return val + "%"; },
    },
    {
      title,
      position: 'bottom',
      axisAlpha: 0,
      borderThickness: 0,
      axisThickness: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
    },
  ],
  dataProvider: data,
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to pad this without modifying your minimum and maximum to be further outside your 0-100 range to accommodate. Since you're using a labelFunction, you can set it up so that you don't display any labels above and below 0-100% if you want, for example:

```
labelFunction: (e, val) => { return (val > 100 || val < 0 ? "" : val + "%"); }
```

Demo below using -10 as a minimum and 110 as a maximum:

```js
var data = [{"rate": 99, "customers": 2421},{"rate": 76,"customers": 100},{"rate": 68,"customers": 1711},{"rate": 38,"customers": 313},{"rate": 94,"customers": 393},{"rate": 57,"customers": 946},{"rate": 99,"customers": 1772},{"rate": 20,"customers": 2168},{"rate": 100,"customers": 754},{"rate": 40,"customers": 121},{"rate": 51,"customers": 2412},{"rate": 15,"customers": 2364},{"rate": 32,"customers": 2161},{"rate": 55,"customers": 1506},{"rate": 29,"customers": 986},{"rate": 0,"customers": 698},{"rate": 4,"customers": 1285},{"rate": 22,"customers": 2108},{"rate": 17,"customers": 2081},{"rate": 79,"customers": 251},{"rate": 48,"customers": 258},{"rate": 41,"customers": 1541},{"rate": 35,"customers": 1132},{"rate": 86,"customers": 1213},{"rate": 1,"customers": 1936},{"rate": 51,"customers": 1737},{"rate": 5,"customers": 2447},{"rate": 60,"customers": 305},{"rate": 37,"customers": 776},{"rate": 64,"customers": 886}];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: 'xy',
  addClassNames: true,
  autoMargins: false,
  marginLeft: 67,
  marginBottom: 55,
  graphs: [{
    //balloonFunction,
    bullet: 'round',
    xField: 'customers',
    yField: 'rate',
    bulletSize: 16,
    lineAlpha: 0, //for testing only
    lineColorField: 'color',
  }],
  valueAxes: [
    {
      title: "Rate (%)",
      borderThickness: 0,
      axisThickness: 2,
      maximum: 110,
      minimum: -10,
      labelFunction: (e,val) => { return (val > 100 || val < 0 ? "" : val + "%"); },
    },
    {
      title: "Customers",
      position: 'bottom',
      axisAlpha: 0,
      borderThickness: 0,
      axisThickness: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
    },
  ],
  dataProvider: data,
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

If you want to remove the extra grid lines from the additional points generated by the new minimum and maximum, you'll have to use guides as your grid lines and labels instead of the ones auto-generated by the chart. For example:

```
valueAxes: [{
    guides: [{
      "value": 0,
      "label": "0%",
      "lineAlpha": .2,
      "tickLength": 5
    },
    // repeat for each tick/grid line
    ],
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickLength": 0,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    // ...
```

Demo:

```js
var data = [{"rate": 99, "customers": 2421},{"rate": 76,"customers": 100},{"rate": 68,"customers": 1711},{"rate": 38,"customers": 313},{"rate": 94,"customers": 393},{"rate": 57,"customers": 946},{"rate": 99,"customers": 1772},{"rate": 20,"customers": 2168},{"rate": 100,"customers": 754},{"rate": 40,"customers": 121},{"rate": 51,"customers": 2412},{"rate": 15,"customers": 2364},{"rate": 32,"customers": 2161},{"rate": 55,"customers": 1506},{"rate": 29,"customers": 986},{"rate": 0,"customers": 698},{"rate": 4,"customers": 1285},{"rate": 22,"customers": 2108},{"rate": 17,"customers": 2081},{"rate": 79,"customers": 251},{"rate": 48,"customers": 258},{"rate": 41,"customers": 1541},{"rate": 35,"customers": 1132},{"rate": 86,"customers": 1213},{"rate": 1,"customers": 1936},{"rate": 51,"customers": 1737},{"rate": 5,"customers": 2447},{"rate": 60,"customers": 305},{"rate": 37,"customers": 776},{"rate": 64,"customers": 886}];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: 'xy',
  addClassNames: true,
  autoMargins: false,
  marginLeft: 67,
  marginBottom: 55,
  graphs: [{
    //balloonFunction,
    bullet: 'round',
    xField: 'customers',
    yField: 'rate',
    bulletSize: 16,
    lineAlpha: 0, //for testing only
    lineColorField: 'color',
  }],
  valueAxes: [
    {
      title: "Rate (%)",
      borderThickness: 0,
      axisThickness: 2,
      maximum: 110,
      minimum: -10,
        guides: [{
          value: 0,
          label: "0%",
          lineAlpha: .2,
          tickLength: 5
        },{
          value: 20,
          label: "20%",
          lineAlpha: .2,
          tickLength: 5
        },{
          value: 40,
          label: "40%",
          lineAlpha: .2,
          tickLength: 5
        },{
          value: 60,
          label: "60%",
          lineAlpha: .2,
          tickLength: 5
        },{
          value: 80,
          label: "80%",
          lineAlpha: .2,
          tickLength: 5
        },{
          value: 100,
          label: "100%",
          lineAlpha: .2,
          tickLength: 5
        }],
        gridAlpha: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        labelsEnabled: false
    },
    {
      title: "Customers",
      position: 'bottom',
      axisAlpha: 0,
      borderThickness: 0,
      axisThickness: 0,
      gridThickness: 0,
    },
  ],
  dataProvider: data,
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, did not know this could be done this way, great solutions, Thank you!